# I am trying to load a 3D model in my react website using Threejs but I get 'Failed to parse source map' error and threejs error in console.log

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, three.js

I am trying to render a 3d model in my website using Threejs and react but I am getting this error. After some testing, it seems to be an error in the `<Model position={[0.025, -0.9, 0]} />` line in the Model3D.js file.

This is the error whiile running the react app.

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/@react-three/drei/node_modules/@mediapipe/tasks-vision/vision_bundle.mjs
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'C:...\node_modules\@react-three\drei\node_modules\@mediapipe\tasks-vision\vision_bundle_mjs.js.map' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:...\node_modules\@react-three\drei\node_modules\@mediapipe\tasks-vision\vision_bundle_mjs.js.map'

webpack compiled with 1 warning
```

And this is the error I get in the console. This error appears over and over in an infinite loop. Is this some error in installing Three.js?

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at Object.update (three.module.js:17707:1)
    at setProgram (three.module.js:29935:1)
    at WebGLRenderer.renderBufferDirect (three.module.js:28843:1)
    at renderObject (three.module.js:29535:1)
    at renderObjects (three.module.js:29504:1)
    at renderScene (three.module.js:29373:1)
    at WebGLRenderer.render (three.module.js:29191:1)
    at render$1 (index-594193f5.esm.js:1522:1)
    at loop (index-594193f5.esm.js:1546:1)
```

This is the js code which is causing the errors

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import { Canvas } from '@react-three/fiber';
import { OrbitControls } from '@react-three/drei';
import { Model } from './Model';

function Model3D() {
    return(
        <Canvas
        camera={{ position: [2, 0, 12.25], fov: 15 }}
        style={{
            backgroundColor: '#111a21',
            width: '100vw',
            height: '100vh',
        }}>
            <ambientLight intensity={1.25} />
            <ambientLight intensity={0.1} />
            <directionalLight intensity={0.4} />
            <Suspense>
                <Model position={[0.025, -0.9, 0]} />
            </Suspense>
            <OrbitControls />
        </Canvas>
)
}
export default Model3D
```

Model is the model.jsx file that I made using gltfjsx model.glb command:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useGLTF } from '@react-three/drei'

export function Model(props) {
  const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF('/model.glb')
  return (
    <group {...props} dispose={null}>
      <primitive object={nodes.Hips} />
      <skinnedMesh geometry={nodes.Wolf3D_Body.geometry} material={materials.Wolf3D_Body} skeleton={nodes.Wolf3D_Body.skeleton} />
      <skinnedMesh geometry={nodes.Wolf3D_Outfit_Bottom.geometry} material={materials.Wolf3D_Outfit_Bottom} skeleton={nodes.Wolf3D_Outfit_Bottom.skeleton} />
      <skinnedMesh geometry={nodes.Wolf3D_Outfit_Footwear.geometry} material={materials.Wolf3D_Outfit_Footwear} skeleton={nodes.Wolf3D_Outfit_Footwear.skeleton} />
      <skinnedMesh geometry={nodes.Wolf3D_Outfit_Top.geometry} material={materials.Wolf3D_Outfit_Top} skeleton={nodes.Wolf3D_Outfit_Top.skeleton} />
      <skinnedMesh geometry={nodes.Wolf3D_Hair.geometry} material={materials.Wolf3D_Hair} skeleton={nodes.Wolf3D_Hair.skeleton} />
      <skinnedMesh geometry={nodes.Wolf3D_Glasses.geometry} material={materials.Wolf3D_Glasses} skeleton={nodes.Wolf3D_Glasses.skeleton} />
      <skinnedMesh geometry={nodes.EyeLeft.geometry} material={materials.Wolf3D_Eye} skeleton={nodes.EyeLeft.skeleton} />
      <skinnedMesh geometry={nodes.EyeRight.geometry} material={materials.Wolf3D_Eye} skeleton={nodes.EyeRight.skeleton} />
      <skinnedMesh geometry={nodes.Wolf3D_Head.geometry} material={materials.Wolf3D_Skin} skeleton={nodes.Wolf3D_Head.skeleton} />
      <skinnedMesh geometry={nodes.Wolf3D_Teeth.geometry} material={materials.Wolf3D_Teeth} skeleton={nodes.Wolf3D_Teeth.skeleton} />
    </group>
  )
}

useGLTF.preload('public/model.glb')
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a .env file in the project's root folder and add this variable to it :
`GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false`

Then restart your react server.